# vscode-remote isolated install

Tags: vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I am working in an isolated enclave, disconnected from Internet access.

I want to install the VSCode Remote extension in this isolated enclave.

Clearly I can download the plug-in to VSCode and install it in this isolated enclave, but is it possible to do all of the necessary dependencies (e.g., the Linux side of the installation for SSH support)?

On the isolated enclave, the remote plug-in cannot reach back to Microsoft's CDN.